# How to temporarily store HTML form file attachment data in WordPress database before sending to Zapier webhook?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, zapier, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have created a custom HTML form on a WordPress page with external CSS and JavaScript files stored in a folder under the WP upload directory. The form collects input data including file attachments like PNG and JPG files. When the form is submitted, it sends the data to Zapier via a webhook.

The issue is that without temporarily storing the file attachments, only the file names are sent to Zapier rather than the actual files. The form needs to send the file attachments to Zapier as part of the form submission action.

How can I temporarily store the HTML form data, specifically the file attachments from the file input fields, in the WordPress database before sending it to Zapier? The webhook doesn't seem to include the actual file attachments unless they are stored somewhere before the form submission.

I need a way to store the file attachment data from the form temporarily in the WordPress database so that the webhook can pick up the files and send them to Zapier along with the rest of the form data.

Let me know if any part of the description needs clarification or expansion. I tried to structure it to clearly explain the specific problem and goal.

Thats my current js code:

```
// Globale Variablen
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const steps = document.querySelectorAll('.step');
let currentStep = 0;

// AJAX Hook für Datei Uploads
wp.ajax.addAction('file_upload', 'handleFileUpload');

// Datei Upload Callback
function handleFileUpload(){

    const file = wp.ajax.getParam('file');

    return wp.ajax.uploadFile(file);

}

// Datei Inputs
const fileInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');

// Form Submit Handler
async function handleFormSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // Form Data
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    // Uploaded Dateien
    const uploaded = [];

    // Dateien uploaden
    for(let input of fileInputs){

        for(let file of input.files){

            const response = wp.ajax.send({
                action: 'file_upload',
                file: file
            });
            console.log(formData);

            const url = response.url;

            uploaded.push({
                name: file.name,
                url: url
            });
            console.log(formData);

        }

    }

    // URLs zur Form Data
    formData.append('uploadedFiles', JSON.stringify(uploaded));
    console.log(formData);

    // Absenden
    submitFormData(formData);
    console.log(formData);
}


// Formular absenden
function submitFormData(formData) {

    fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxxx/yyyyyy/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    });

}

form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);

// Funktion zum Anzeigen eines Schritts
function showStep(stepIndex) {
    steps.forEach(step => step.classList.remove('active'));
    steps[stepIndex].classList.add('active');
}

// Funktionen für einzelnen Schritte
function handleHandelsregistereintrag(value) {
    // Referenzen auf die Input Felder
    const inputHrnummer = document.querySelector('input[name="hrnummer"]');
    const inputAmtsgericht = document.querySelector('input[name="amtsgericht"]');
    const handelsregisterDetails = document.getElementById('handelsregisterDetails');
    if (value === 'Ja') {
        handelsregisterDetails.style.display = 'block';
        inputHrnummer.classList.remove('optional');
        inputAmtsgericht.classList.remove('optional');
    } else {
        handelsregisterDetails.style.display = 'none';
        inputHrnummer.classList.add('optional');
        inputAmtsgericht.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function handleRechtsform(value) {
    // Referenzen auf die Input Felder
    const gbRName = document.getElementById('gbRName');
    const gbRNameLabel = document.getElementById('gbRNameLabel');
    if (value === '3') {
        gbRName.style.display = 'block';
        gbRNameLabel.style.display = 'block';
        gbRName.classList.remove('optional');
    } else {
        gbRName.style.display = 'none';
        gbRNameLabel.style.display = 'none';
        gbRName.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function handleWeiterePersonen(value) {
    const weiterePersonenDetails = document.getElementById('weiterePersonenDetails');
    const vornamePerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="vornamePerson2"]');
    const nachnamePerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="nachnamePerson2"]');
    const strassePerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="strassePerson2"]');
    const hausnummerPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="hausnummerPerson2"]');
    const postleitzahlPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="postleitzahlPerson2"]');
    const stadtPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="stadtPerson2"]');
    const erlernterBerufPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="erlernterBerufPerson2"]');
    const geburtsdatumPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="geburtsdatumPerson2"]');
    const staatsangehoerigkeitPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="staatsangehoerigkeitPerson2"]');
    const geburtslandPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="geburtslandPerson2"]');
    const geburtsortPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="geburtsortPerson2"]');
    const pruefungFachrichtungPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="pruefungFachrichtungPerson2"]');
    const pruefungOrtPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="pruefungOrtPerson2"]');
    const pruefungDatumPerson2 = document.querySelector('input[name="pruefungDatumPerson2"]');

    if (value === 'Ja') {
        weiterePersonenDetails.style.display = 'block';
        vornamePerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        nachnamePerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        strassePerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        hausnummerPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        postleitzahlPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        stadtPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        erlernterBerufPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        geburtsdatumPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        staatsangehoerigkeitPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        geburtslandPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        geburtsortPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        pruefungFachrichtungPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        pruefungOrtPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
        pruefungDatumPerson2.classList.remove('optional');
    } else {
        weiterePersonenDetails.style.display = 'none';
        vornamePerson2.classList.add('optional');
        nachnamePerson2.classList.add('optional');
        strassePerson2.classList.add('optional');
        hausnummerPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        postleitzahlPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        stadtPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        erlernterBerufPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        geburtsdatumPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        staatsangehoerigkeitPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        geburtslandPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        geburtsortPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        pruefungFachrichtungPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        pruefungOrtPerson2.classList.add('optional');
        pruefungDatumPerson2.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function handleMitgliedschaftIHK(value) {
    const mitgliedschaftIHKDetails = document.getElementById('mitgliedschaftIHKDetails');
    const ihk = document.querySelector('input[name="ihk"]');
    const ihkGewerbe = document.querySelector('input[name="ihkGewerbe"]');
    const umsatzanteil = document.querySelector('input[name="umsatzanteil"]');
    const anzahlMitarbeiter = document.querySelector('input[name="anzahlMitarbeiter"]');
    if (value === 'Ja') {
        mitgliedschaftIHKDetails.style.display = 'block';
        ihk.classList.remove('optional');
        ihkGewerbe.classList.remove('optional');
        umsatzanteil.classList.remove('optional');
        anzahlMitarbeiter.classList.remove('optional');
    } else {
        mitgliedschaftIHKDetails.style.display = 'none';
        ihk.classList.add('optional');
        ihkGewerbe.classList.add('optional');
        umsatzanteil.classList.add('optional');
        anzahlMitarbeiter.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function handleFilialen(value) {
    const filialenDetails = document.getElementById('filialenDetails');
    const strasseF1 = document.getElementById('strasse-f1');
    const hausnummerF1 = document.getElementById('hausnummer-f1');
    const plzF1 = document.getElementById('plz-f1');
    const stadtF1 = document.getElementById('stadt-f1');

    if (value === 'Ja') {
        filialenDetails.style.display = 'block';
        strasseF1.classList.remove('optional');
        hausnummerF1.classList.remove('optional');
        plzF1.classList.remove('optional');
        stadtF1.classList.remove('optional');

    } else {
        filialenDetails.style.display = 'none';
        strasseF1.classList.add('optional');
        hausnummerF1.classList.add('optional');
        plzF1.classList.add('optional');
        stadtF1.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function handleGewerbeVergangenheit(selectElement) {
    const gewerbeVergangenheitDetails = document.getElementById('gewerbeVergangenheitDetails');
    const gewerbeVon = document.getElementById('gewerbeVon');
    const gewerbeBis = document.getElementById('gewerbeBis');
    const gewerbeOrt = document.getElementById('gewerbeOrt');

    if (selectElement.value === 'Ja') {
        gewerbeVon.classList.remove('optional');
        gewerbeBis.classList.remove('optional');
        gewerbeOrt.classList.remove('optional');
        gewerbeVergangenheitDetails.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        gewerbeVergangenheitDetails.style.display = 'none';
        gewerbeVon.classList.add('optional');
        gewerbeBis.classList.add('optional');
        gewerbeOrt.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function handleBetriebsuebernahme(selectElement) {
    const betriebsuebernahmeDetails = document.getElementById('betriebsuebernahmeDetails');
    const betriebsuebernahmeDatum = document.getElementById('betriebsuebernahmeDatum');
    const fruehererInhaber = document.querySelector('input[name="fruehererInhaber"]');

    if (selectElement.value === 'Ja') {
        fruehererInhaber.classList.remove('optional');
        betriebsuebernahmeDatum.classList.remove('optional');
        betriebsuebernahmeDetails.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        betriebsuebernahmeDetails.style.display = 'none';
        betriebsuebernahmeDatum.classList.add('optional');
        fruehererInhaber.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function handleSitzverlagerung(selectElement) {
    const sitzverlagerungDetails = document.getElementById('sitzverlagerungDetails');
    const sitzverlagerungDatum = document.querySelector('input[name="sitzverlagerungDatum"]');
    if (selectElement.value === 'Ja') {
        sitzverlagerungDetails.style.display = 'block';
        sitzverlagerungDatum.classList.remove('optional');
    } else {
        sitzverlagerungDetails.style.display = 'none';
        sitzverlagerungDatum.classList.add('optional');
    }
}

function nextStep() {

    // Alle Eingabefelder des aktuellen Schritts auswählen
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.step.active input:not(.optional), .step.active select:not(.optional)');

    let isValid = true;

    // Überprüfe jedes Eingabefeld
    inputs.forEach(input => {

        // Wenn Feld leer, setze isValid auf false
        if (!input.value) {
            isValid = false;
        }

    });

    // Wenn isValid false, breche ab
    if (!isValid) {
        alert('Bitte fülle alle Felder aus!');
        return;
    }

    currentStep++;
    showStep(currentStep);
}

// Funktion für vorherigen Schritt
function previousStep() {
    if (currentStep >= 0) {
        currentStep--;
        showStep(currentStep);
    }
}

// Funktionen für Sidebar
const sidebarLinks = document.getElementById('sidebarLinks');
const currentStepP = document.getElementById('currentStepP');

// Funktion zum Anzeigen eines Schritts
function showStep(stepIndex) {
    steps.forEach(step => step.classList.remove('active'));
    steps[stepIndex].classList.add('active');

    // Aktualisiere Sidebar
    updateSidebar();
}

// Aktuellen Schritt anzeigen
function showCurrentStep() {
    currentStepP.innerText = steps[currentStep].querySelector('h2').textContent;
}

// Sidebar updaten
function updateSidebar() {

    // Schleife durch Schritte
    for (let i = 0; i < currentStep; i++) {

        // Prüfen ob Link schon vorhanden
        let link = document.getElementById('stepLink-' + i);

        if (!link) {
            // Neu erstellen wenn nicht da
            addStepLink(i);
        }

    }

    // Aktuellen Schritt anzeigen
    showCurrentStep();

}

// Beim Laden aufrufen
updateSidebar();

// Click Handler beim Link hinzufügen
function addStepLink(stepNum) {

    const link = document.createElement('a');

    link.id = 'stepLink-' + stepNum;

    link.addEventListener('click', handleStepLinkClick);

    link.textContent = steps[stepNum].querySelector('h2').textContent;

    sidebarLinks.appendChild(link);

}

// Click Handler Funktion
function handleStepLinkClick(event) {

    // Aktuellen Schritt ausblenden
    steps[currentStep].classList.remove('active');

    // Neuen currentStep setzen
    currentStep = parseInt(event.target.id.split('-')[1]);

    // Neuen Schritt einblenden
    steps[currentStep].classList.add('active');

    // Sidebar aktualisieren
    updateSidebar();

}
```

Here my current test html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gewerbeform1.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <form action="https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyy/" id="existenzgruendungForm" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" id="base64Files">
        <input type="file" id="anhaenge">
        <!-- Step 7 -->
        <div class="step active" id="step0">
            <h2>Schritt 8 - Gewerbeamt auswählen</h2><br>
            <h3>Bitte wähle das für dich zuständige Gewerbeamt aus:</h3>

            <label for="zusatzblattPerson2">Wenn weitere Angaben erforderlich sind, bitte Zusatzblatt verwenden!</label>
            <input multiple id="zusatzblattPerson2" name="zusatzblattPerson2" type="file">

            <!-- Button zum Weitergehen zum nächsten Schritt -->
            <button class="weiterButton" onclick="nextStep()" type="button">Weiter</button>
            <!-- Button zum Zurückgehen zum vorherigen Schritt -->
            <button class="zurueckButton" onclick="previousStep()" type="button">Zurück</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Step 16 - Zahlung -->
        <div class="step" id="step1">
            <h2>Schritt 9 - Zahlung</h2>
            <p>Dies ist die Gebühr für unseren Service zzgl. Gebühr der Behörde</p>
            <br><input type="checkbox" id="agbDatenschutz" name="agbDatenschutz" checked>
            <p style="display: inline; font-size: 18px;">Ich akzeptiere die AGB</p><br><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="korrektheit" name="korrektheit" checked>
            <p style="display: inline; font-size: 18px;">Ich bestätige hiermit die Korrektheit meiner Angaben sowie die
                Übernahme
                der Kosten die vom Gewerbeamt/der Gemeinde erhobenen werden und erteile mein-gewerbeantrag.de eine
                Vollmacht für
                die Erstellung meines Gewerbeantrags und dessen Versand, sowie für die Korrespondenz mit der
                Behörde.</p><br>
            <br>
            <!-- Button zum Zurückgehen zum vorherigen Schritt -->
            <button class="zurueckButton" onclick="previousStep()" type="button">Zurück</button>
            <!-- Button zum Weitergehen zum nächsten Schritt -->
            <button id="submitButton" class="weiterButton" type="submit">Weiter zur Zahlung</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    <h5>Bearbeitete Schritte</h5>
    <ul id="sidebarLinks">
    </ul>
    <h5>Aktueller Schritt</h5>
    <div id="currentStep"><p id="currentStepP"></p></div>
</div>

<script src="gewerbeform1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```